# Question About Eager Loading Syntax

Tags: array, eager-loading

I am trying to add eager loading to a query. The original query was as follows (‘sticky’ is a custom lightswitch field for marking sticky entries):

```
{% set news = craft.entries.section('news').order('sticky desc, postDate desc').limit(9) %}
```

Is the following ok syntax for adding eager loading?

```
{% set news = craft.entries.section('news').order('sticky desc, postDate desc').limit(9).find({
    with: [
        ['newsHighlightImage', {
            withTransforms: ['newsMedium', 'newsSmall']
        }]
    ]
}) %}
```

I ask because although the above seems to work, in the examples in [the documentation](https://docs.craftcms.com/v2/templating/eager-loading-elements.html), the find/with bits come right after the section parameter. But if I do it that way, I get an error about not being able to apply the “order” method. I reckon that’s because find() turns the result into an array so “order” is not longer available. But I couldn’t figure out the correct carry syntax to make it work that way. Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks!

Willhaus

Answer (score 1):

How about stacking all the element query params into a single object?

```
{% set entries = craft.entries({
    section: 'news',
    order: 'sticky desc, postDate desc',
    limit: 9,
    with: [
        ['newsHighlightImage', {
            withTransforms: ['newsMedium', 'newsSmall']
        }]
    ]
}) %}
```

Also, I don't believe you need to use the `find()` function here. The examples in the documentation only use `find()` when eager-loading just the image transforms related to a single asset field.

```
{% set assets = entry.assetsField.find({
    withTransforms: [
        'heroImage',
        { width: 100, height: 100 }
    ]
}) %}
```

Comment: Tried it and it works, thank you. Funny thing is that I was going to say it seems at first that it's exactly like mine but with a different syntax, but dev mode says it run one additional query than mine for some reason…

Comment: ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ Eager loading magic? Who knows. Also magnets... how do they work? ;)